# Show dictionary [key, value] in combobox but only [key] after selection

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a dictionary which I want to allow the keys to be selected in a combobox but also display the value without having to create another column.

For instance, if my dictionary consists of 3 items for now

```
Dictionary<string, double> test = new Dictionary<string, double>();
    //KEY , VALUE
    //"Item1" , 4.0
    //"Item2" , 4.5
    //"Item3" , 5.0
```

I want the combobox pulldown list to display the available selections showing BOTH key and value

```
[Item1, 4.0]
[Item2, 4.5]
[Item3, 5.0]
```

and say if `[Item2, 4.5]` is selected then only the key is displayed in the combobox as the current selection, in this case the following would display after selection...

`Item2`

I've tried the following but this shows `[key,value]` in both the combobox selection list and after selection

```
comboboxColumn2.SelectedValuePath= "Key";
comboboxColumn2.ItemsSource = test;
```

I've also tried using combinations with `comboboxColumn2.DisplayMemberPath= "Value";` but cannot get it formatted as I would like.

Can anyone say if it's possible and what the correct syntax is?

EDIT:

The combobox are actually ComboboxColumns so there are only 2 events available which don't appear very useful

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Department Id" x:Name="comboboxColumn1"
            SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Department Id}" />
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Department Id" x:Name="comboboxColumn2"
        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Department Name}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this on code behind here it is :

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="168,100,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" DropDownOpened="comboBox1_DropDownOpened" DropDownClosed="comboBox1_DropDownClosed" />

public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var source = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        source.Add("Item1", 0.4);
        source.Add("Item2", 0.3);
        source.Add("Item3", 0.1);

        var formateDSource = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            formateDSource.Add(string.Format("[{0}, {1}]", item.Key, item.Value), item.Key);
        }

        comboBox1.ItemsSource = formateDSource;
        comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
    }

    private void comboBox1_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Key";
    }

    private void comboBox1_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
    }
```

I just created an formatedSource and then changed the displayMemberPath according to your description.

Hope it helps